# Hyperledger fabric Blockchain Info

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have fabric network setup with 2 organisations, install the fabcar chain code and I am able to create the transaction.

1. I am able to get the blockchain info using the below cmd inside docker, work well. I want get blockinfo using fabric sdk is it possible? If yes, how, any example would be help full.

> peer channel getinfo -c mychannel

2. Is it possible to get the blockhash or blockchain info using chaincode?
3. I am creating multiple transactions it works well, just wanna know does the transaction created by user have any sequence number/none. If yes from where it is fetched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, check SDK API. This can be helpful: https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/Channel.html#queryBlock__anchor . It makes you query by block ID.
2. You can use SDK too for this.
3. Every transaction has a unique identifier ID which is the TxId, it is an hash string. Transactions does not have an index but blocks does.